# Invalid Date in firefox

Tags: javascript, date

In js I write following row:

```
 new Date("2014-12-01 00:20:00.0")
```

In chrome it works good but in Mozilla I see error `Invalid Date`

this string comes to me from another function thus I cannot change it.

Hwow can I set Date format for this constructor?

Comment: Which ff Version do you use?

Comment: I checked it, he date part is okay, the time is the problem. I will look at it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have the solution. After reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

I found a supported Format, which is near to yours. ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format.
"2011-10-10T14:48:00"

So if you do this before parsing, it will work.

```
<script>
    d1 = new Date("2014-12-01 00:20:00.0".replace(/ /g, "T"));
    alert(d1);
</script>
```

Checked with FF, IE, OP and Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [MDN documentation Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]);
```

For your case :

```
new Date(2014, 12, 01, 0, 20, 0, 0);
```

Comment: But you can also use new Date(dateString);

Comment: @Alexandre L. it is very uncomfortable to parse my string